# Zend fetchAll foreach 2 times run dont loop 2nd time;

Tags: php, zend-framework, foreach

This is very simple to understand

Image Class

```
<?php
class Image extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'images';

    public function getList() {
        return $this->fetchAll();
    }
}?>
```

My PHP Code

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

$imgTable = new Image();  // Create Object

$imgList = $imgTable->getList(); // fetch Data

$template = new Template('portfolio'); // Initialize Template and tell which template to pick

$template->imgList = $imgList; // set template variable

$template->render(); // Generate Template output

?>
```

I can access template variable inside template using $this

Below code is from inside the template

```
$xback = 0;
foreach ($this->imgList as $images) {
    echo 'imageArray[' . $xback . '] = "' . $images['sef'] . '";';
    $xback++;
}
?>
.......
<?php


foreach ($this->imgList as $images) {

?>
    <div class="portfolio_item">
    <img src="<?php echo PATH_WEB . $images['image_thumb'] ?>" height="146" width="209" />
    <div class="title"><?php echo $images['image_title'] ?></div>
    <div class="right link">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="showItemDetails('<?php echo $images['sef'] ?>')">View Details</a>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php
}

?>
```

Above code is working fine, but below some few lines, I have to iterate over the same data again dont output any thing. If I comment the first one, 2nd starts working.

First one is to create the JS array and is in head section, 
Second part is in HTML to display images

I hope its a pointer issue, I may have to set the loop current item to start, but I am not understanding it right now .... `reset($this->imgList)` didnt worked

please help

Comment: Are you sure that $images['image_thumb'] and $images['image_title'] are actually set?

Comment: Yes they are outputting the content. I am new to zend , and I am just using their DB in my own hand crafted cms typo thing... class is initiated by `class Image extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{` and i simply used `$this->fetchall()` and I am getting out put

Comment: Have you tried replacing: 

`$this->imgList = $this->fetchAll();`

with

`$imgList = $this->fetchAll();`

And then replacing the rest of the references to $this->imgList

Comment: $this->imgList is just to give you the idea, so basically $imgList = $fetchAll(); and then I have passed that into my template variable. and inside template i am accessing it via $this->imgList

Comment: I have updated my question again and now I include almost all of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the `fetchAll` call, try this:

```
<?php
class Image extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'images';
    protected $images;

    public function getList() {

        // Employ lazy loading pattern to load images if they aren't set yet
        if (!isset($this->$images)) {
            $this->images = $this->fetchAll();
        }

        return $this->images;
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Not sure, it's possible that after the initial `fetchAll` call that the DBO drops the result set, so it's better to localize upon first request so you can call multiple times.